# 2 hours lost in microseconds

Tags: c#, datetime

I've got a timestamp in microseconds since 1.1.1970. I've tried to convert it into

```
          yyyy.MM.dd HH.mm.ss.ffffff
```

using DateTime.
An example is: 1337060932000000 microseconds
the result should be May 15 2012, 7.48

But the result I get is 2 hours off.
What could be the reason?

Comment: Well it might be in UTC ! ! How are you doing it

Comment: Consider local time offset and daylight savings.

Comment: @Chris how did you calculate the result? Did you keep all the date-time peculiarities you're going to stumble upon in mind? e.g. leap years, leap seconds...

Comment: thank you this was the reason, i was a blockhead. I have to add the 2 hours to the GMT to get the german time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the hints.
I solved the problem this way:

```
    int offset = 2;
    DateTime d = new DateTime(1979,1,1, offset,0,0);
```

This example is simplified. The offset is specified in an external file so you can modify it easily for different time zones.

Answer (score 2):

You are most likely getting a UTC date, since the Unix epoch is this time zone. Make sure you create the base date as so:

```
var epoch = new DateTime(1970,1,1, 0,0,0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
```

Once you have that, you can do something like:

```
var localTime = epoch.AddMilliseconds(microseconds / 1000).ToLocalTime();
```

If `microseconds` is the value you provided above, the value you get is `15/05/2012 07:48:52` which is what you expected I think.

Be careful when using `ToLocalTime` though, since you can only be sure that this will be the local time zone of computer your software is running and, from experience, I can tell you it's not always the time zone you think.